# MongoDB Not equal isn't the opposite of equal

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I run the following:

```
db.restaurants.find({'grades.grade': 'A'}, {'grades.grade':1})
```

Then I return all the documents that have a grade with an 'A'.  That being, any document with *at least one* 'A' but there may be other grades.  e.g:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c9a7038cc7f52917313091"),
    "grades" : [ 
        {
            "grade" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "grade" : "B"
        }, 
        {
            "grade" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "grade" : "A"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I use the `$ne` operator:

```
db.restaurants.find({'grades.grade': {$ne: 'A'}}, {'grades.grade':1})
```

Then I return all the documents that have *all* grades not equal to 'A'.

e.g.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c9a7038cc7f52917313245"),
    "grades" : [ 
        {
            "grade" : "B"
        }, 
        {
            "grade" : "B"
        }, 
        {
            "grade" : "C"
        }, 
        {
            "grade" : "B"
        }, 
        {
            "grade" : "B"
        }
    ]
}
```

Why does `$ne` match all grades, but equal to match any grade?

> NB: The same behaviour seems to be true in `$in` ans `$nin`.  `$in` matches any document whereas `$nin` matches all documents.
>
> NB2: `$not` exhibits the behaviour too.

Comment: The big flaw in how you are thinking about this is evident in your term "documents". In each case there is only **one** document and therefore the conditions would apply. Arrays are not subject to separate condtions in themselves or applied in any combination of elements. There is simply a value that either matches the tested `grade.grades` or not. Only one condition need be true per "document" and it is. Applied logic to arrays is a completely different process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question, and I agree that from a functional perspective you are right: There should be a way to "negate" `equals` in a way that is logically "give me anything that contains something that is not `A`".

But I think the the way Mongo works here makes sense from a formal logic perspective. If you think about it logically, then the query `db.restaurants.find({'grades.grade': 'A'})` returns

```
(grades[0].grade == 'A' || grades[1].grade == 'A' || grades[2].grade == 'A'|| grades[3].grade == 'A'...)
```

Basic formal logic says that the negation of the above statement is

```
(grades[0].grade != 'A' && grades[1].grade != 'A' && grades[2].grade != 'A'&& grades[3].grade != 'A'...)
```

Which is exactly what you got by using `$ne`.

Comment: (all x in X where x == "A") + (all x in X where x != "A") = X

Comment: Aye.  Not is the set that is not covered by the equality.  Therefore, the count of both will equal the total documents.  Still unexpected though.

Comment: I agree that it's unexpected. I was just trying to see the logic in the behavior.

Comment: The more my brain thinks about it the more 'right' it seems.  Your answer, rather than what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequence of basic De Morgan logical negation.

NOT (A AND B) means (NOT A) OR (NOT B)

This can be directly translated to set theory, where disjunction (OR) means union and conjunction (AND) means intersection.

When you apply equals you're asking for ANY value that matches(disjunction). But when you negate that, you negate every single match as per De Morgan.